# Making binary of a web application. http server in memory image

Tags: webserver, common-lisp, binaryfiles

Is it possible to in Common Lisp to make an executable file from a current image that includes an http server, hunchentoot, postgresql connection library, postmodern. etc.?

I have made a binary file that includes those and can run some simple html pages. Before saving the binary system works. After saving the binary it can be launched by double clicking. And it includes the server listening the port before told to but from browser I cannot reach to the pages before I could do.

What am I missing?

I have used ccl on mac osx 10.9.3.

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question.  Show your configuration and delivery script, and show the problem that you run into.

Comment: no delivery script. I made it by `save-application` of ccl on freeBSD. By the way I have now updated the bottom line of above question by changing mac osx to freebsd. because on maces x I cannot make executable from ccl, I save it but cannot execute it. on terminal tons of lines given when fired up. Also the executable done on freebsd does not work on mac osx is that normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to save the image when everything is already running. Instead you should save the image after you've loaded your code and have the start of the image / the binary starting up the http server, making the database connections etc. *Edit*: If you save your image with connections already in place, these won't automatically be re-established when you fire up the image later on, you have to have code in place that does that for you.

Comment: Do you mean one should load http server db lib and all your functions you have written; and with this all loaded state one should save the image or make the binary; fire up this saved lisp, and a t this stage run the functions that start http server or db connections etc. Am I right? If so why connections should be reestablished and not automatically established when I run the binary?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I mentioned re-establishing not working only as an explanation why saving the image after you have everything running doesn't work.

Comment: Then one can have the top-level function of the saved lisp to be a function that reestablishes connections only and create other things that cannot be saved in the saved lisp.